# Excel table is not maintaining the formatting, when a new row is added. Any advice?

Tags: microsoft-excel

First, I have some cells which have a custom format applied:

[image]

Then, I convert the spanning range into a Table:

[image]

Then I set the Table format to be "None", so that the pre-formatted cells remain formatted but the column in the middle appears unformatted:

[image]

Now I format the empty column's header so that it appears blank, as if the column itself were not part of the table:

[image]

When I add a new row to the table, it doesn't have a bottom border:

[image]

The Excel Table I have defined automatically expands when I input information into a new row, as you would expect. However, it does not keep the same formatting as the row above and all the other rows: it keeps the same colours, but does not include the bottom-cell border.

Any idea what is going on? I believe it has something to do with the "blank" column as it works without it, but is there any way of me getting it to work with the blank column (as although it doesn't seem relevant in the example shown, I actually need it).

Thanks

Comment: what formatting is missing, from the images I looks like the formatting is there ?

Comment: Bottom-cell border - there should be a black-border around each cell, but the bottom row is missing the black line at the bottom of the cell

Comment: sorry ignore me, what happens when you add another additional row ?

Comment: Basically the 'Test' row looks perfect if I insert another new row (it now has the underline I wanted), but that *now* new row is missing the bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue. I think it's caused by the fact that you've selected "None" for the table style. The only way I've found to retain the bottom border on newly added rows is to create a custom Table style and add Bottom Border to the "Whole Table" element. On the Table Design tab, drop-down the Table Styles list, then select "New Table Style" to create a new style for your table.

This has the perhaps undesirable effect of putting the border on the bottom of the "blank" column as well.

[image]

However, perhaps that's something you can live with for the benefit of having the bottom border retained on the other columns of newly added rows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I think you're right that this will be the only solution. I think though that rather than the "None" table style, the problem actually lies in the Blank column - as when I've tested the table without the blank column and with the "None" table style, the problem goes away!

Comment: Fair enough. But if you remove the blank column, you may as well use a custom table style instead of individual cell-styles. :)

Comment: Aha yeah indeed :-) I do need the blank columns, so I'll just have to decide which way to go!